# Is there a way to detect the source of android app page view on google play?

Tags: android, google-play, referrals, pageviews

I basically want to detect the path from where users are getting to my android app market page.

1. What are the different keywords for which users are searching and thus viewing (if not necessarily downloading) my android app.
2. If they are clicking on my app from top free / top new free/ top free games

I can see that the above information being passed in the browser when I click on app icon through a certain path (like search, featured, top free etc.)

I want to catch this information and if possible, analyze so that I can better optimize my app performance on google play.

PLease Note: I am NOT talking about referral tracking which is provided when a referral link is clicked and that app is downloaded through google play app. I just want to analyze the behaviour of user when they are browsing the google play on their browser and finally reaching to my app display page.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there is a way to hook in Analytics into the Google Playstore. I'd be interested if there was a way to do it.

Comment: I found that this information was initially passed on to the app by earlier versions of google market, but in later versions this was removed. This info is critical for optimizing the app discovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. As far as I know, Google doesn't expose that information for the most part. As for the information you found passed to your app by earlier version of the Market app, that was specific to the Market app and *is* referral tracking. It just happens that you're talking about organic referrals.

Answer (score 0):

recently Google play and Google Analytics announced they would start sharing data with easy integrations, if you already have integrated the sdk in your app, just follow the process to enable sharing data. and you will start seeing data from both platforms including keywords and installation sources according to this link. http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-integration.html